# Basic snapping isn't working

Tags: snapping

I'm just beginning with Blender and am following a lovely youtube tutorial to learn how to use it. In this tutorial we're making a set of Minecraft pillars to animate. In his video the blocks/mesh snaps into place absolutely perfectly each and every time. I have had no such luck. I've experimented with all the options under the snap to drop down and every mesh still ends up being off.

My most recent attempt had the points at the following: X -0.0147, Y -0.044 and Z 1.998 where they were supposed to be X 0, Y 0 and Z 2. That is the best I've been able to accomplish without manually changing the values in object properties. I realize leaving it as is and continuing to build the pillar will result in greater and greater differences which will make the final product completely wrong. I am not the greatest with math and do not care for the idea of having to calculate the position of everything I make because the snapping does not work.

I did try to post this problem on the Blender subreddit but not a single person saw it there. Does anyone have thoughts on this or am I just going to have to become better friends with mathematics?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell without seeing your project, but a common error is to try and line up the faces/edges/verts you are trying to snap together. Remember you must put your _mouse cursor_ over the spot you want to snap to - don't try and line up the pieces the way they should look (unintuitive I know). Once the mouse cursor is in the right spot, you should see the piece snap into place.

Comment: It's possible that your starting point is slightly off a whole number. Snapping by increment does just that, it increments the position, So 0.0032 becomes 1.0032 etc. There is a setting in 2.9 called "Absolute Grid Snap" that snaps to a whole number on the grid regardless of where it started from, that might be what you need.

Comment: @Psyonic Thank you so much. Absolute grid is exactly what I needed. Does this get any easier? I don't know if this is for me if spending 2 weeks to stack 10 of the original mesh blocks accurately on top of each other is supposed to be super easy beginner stuff.

Comment: @Brett lol, it gets much easier as you get used to the interface! I've been at this for 3 years now and have only just begun (attempting) to answer questions here :)
I will put this comment as an answer so others can find it, please mark it as correct (and I get my points :)

Answer (score 2):

In the snap settings, activate the setting "Absolute Grid Snap". It snaps to a whole number on the grid regardless of where it started from. So if you start dragging from 2.346, it will snap to exactly 2.